# Reading and appending files into a spark dataframe

Tags: pyspark

I have created an empty dataframe and started adding to it, by reading each file. But one of the files has more number of columns than the previous. How can I select only the columns in the first file for all the other files?

```
from pyspark.sql import SparkSession

from pyspark.sql import SQLContext

from pyspark.sql.types import StructType
import os, glob
spark = SparkSession.builder.\           
    config("spark.jars.packages","saurfang:spark-sas7bdat:2.0.0-s_2.11")\            
    .enableHiveSupport().getOrCreate()
fpath=''
schema = StructType([])
sc = spark.sparkContext
df_spark=spark.createDataFrame(sc.emptyRDD(), schema)
files=glob.glob(fpath +'*.sas7bdat')
for i,f in enumerate(files):
    if i == 0:
       df=spark.read.format('com.github.saurfang.sas.spark').load(f)   
       df_spark= df
    else:
         df=spark.read.format('com.github.saurfang.sas.spark').load(f) 
         df_spark=df_spark.union(df)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can provide your own schema while creating a dataframe.
for example, I have two files `emp1.csv & emp2.csv` having diffrent schema.

```
id,empname,empsalary
1,Vikrant,55550

id,empname,empsalary,age,country
2,Raghav,10000,32,India

schema = StructType([
            StructField("id", IntegerType(), True),
            StructField("name", StringType(), True),
            StructField("salary", IntegerType(), True)])

file_path="file:///home/vikct001/user/vikrant/inputfiles/testfiles/emp*.csv"
df=spark.read.format("com.databricks.spark.csv").option("header", "true").schema(schema).load(file_path)
```

Specifying a schema not only addresses data types & format issue but it's also necessary to improve a performance.

There are other options  as well if you need to drop malformed records, but this will also drop the records which are having nulls or which doesn't fit as per schema provided. 
It may skip those records also having multiple delimiters and junk characters or an empty file.

```
.option("mode", "DROPMALFORMED")
```

FAILFAST mode will throw an exception as and when it found malformed record.

```
.option("mode", "FAILFAST")
```

you can also use map function to select the elements of your choice and exclude others while building a dataframe.

```
df=spark.read.format('com.databricks.spark.csv').option("header", "true").load(file_path).rdd.map(lambda x :(x[0],x[1],x[2])).toDF(["id","name","salary"])
```

you need to set header as 'true' in both the cases, otherwise it will include your csv header as first record for your dataframe.

Comment: df=spark.read.format("com.databricks.spark.csv").option("header", "true").schema(schema).load(file_path)  worked for me , other than having data type mismatch. couldn't find more info on which exact row is causing the issue.  Thank you vikrant rana.

Comment: Yeah. That will work. rdd method will be useful when you have to delete the columns if they are not in specific order or have to delete the columns in between. In that case you may need to modify your map function as well. I mean it depends on your requirement.

Answer (score 1):

You can get the fieldnames from the schema of the first file and then use the array of fieldnames to select the columns from all other files.

```
fields = df.schema.fieldNames
```

You can use the fields array to select the columns from all other datasets. Following is the scala code for that.

```
df=spark.read.format('com.github.saurfang.sas.spark').load(f).select(fields(0),fields.drop(1):_*)
```